# Exchanging the HDD on a Windows 7 Notebook

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I plan to buy a notebook that is equipped with an old magnetic disk drive and Windows 7 Pro 64-bit and eventually want to replace the drive for a new SSD, later.

Is it possible to migrate a Windows 7 installation to another HDD by just making a 1:1 copy of the old drive?

I ask because on Windows XP exchanging the HDD by coping it had not worked without tricking the installed Windows XP (this issue is caused by the HDD's serial number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while it is easy to clone (ghost) the disk and replace it, you may consider a different approach with an SSD where disk space is a rather scarce commmodity.

*for example, the cost per GB of an Intel X-25m SSD easily exceeds 7 dollar.*

it's better to trim the heck out of windows 7 (vLite) and install the OS from scratch without the bloat that comes with a OEM installation.

*so, if you're able to save 10 GB installation size, you saved disk space worth $70 or more.*

Comment: As I understood the problem that XP had with cloning are not present in Windows 7 anymore. Do you actually tried this out?

Comment: i have to do this quite frequently (cloning drives with Ghost, Ghost Enterpise v11, that is, not their pathetic consumer product which is a different software alltogether) and never had any troubles, regardless the operating system.